# Based on the length how to validate confirm password in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

Codepen link https://codepen.io/santoshch/pen/bGgKNWV

```js
 
 
  <div
                      v-if="this.submitted && $v.user.confirmPassword.$error"
                      class="error-messages-pass"
                    >
                     
                      <span
                        v-if="
                          user.confirmPassword &&
                          !$v.user.confirmPassword.sameAsPassword
                        "
                        >kindly re-try</span
                      >
                    </div>
```

Need it as,  if for suppose, in 5th character in confirm password is mismatching then it will show error message in 5th character itself saying ,'‘kindly re-try’.

But issue is now it is checking with password field, not at specified character.

For example if user enter in password field "qwerty"
and in confirm password field if user enter "qweee"

Now in 4th character, character is mismatching, so then i need to get err message as kindly reerty.

Comment: Can any one please help me on this?

Comment: the code is already validating both if there is mismatch in input it display as must be identical it is correctly working for me

Comment: @Dineshkarthik, Yes validating both fields, if mismatch in input is working fine, But need it as For example i am entering in password field as "asdfg" and in confirm password field if i enter "asddd" then here in confirm password field, 4th character is wrong with password field, then error message should display like "try again"

Comment: @Dineshkarthik But in the current codepen code, It is only  validating both if there is mismatch in input it display as must be identical

Comment: @Dineshkarthik Any suggestions please.

Comment: bro sorry for delay now only opened stack over flow i am not well in vue just try by external js code for comparing two values and display as retry